# Can't open the specified file input stream from file (Docker)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to read an excel data from the following path: `file:///Users/karen/prog/files/statuses.xlsx`

But I'm constantly receiving an error:

```
rest-module_1  | 2020-03-24 10:02:04.504 ERROR 72 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Can't open the specified file input stream from file: '/Users/karen/prog/files/statuses.xlsx'] with root cause
rest-module_1  | 
rest-module_1  | java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/karen/prog/files/statuses.xlsx (No such file or directory)
```

This is my code:

```
public XSSFWorkbook getExcelWorkbook(String path) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException, URISyntaxException {
        if (path.startsWith("file://")) {
            System.out.println(path);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new File(new URI(path)));
            return wb;
        } else {
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
            return wb;
        }
    }
```

What may be wrong? If I navigate through a terminal to the 'files' folder and run 'pwd' - it will show the exact path that I've mentioned above. I'm using Mac
I have read and write permissions on that file:
[image]

I'm running the app from docker, could this be an error?
This is my docker-compose file:

```
services:

  rest-module:
    build:
      context: ./Status
    image: statusimage
    ports: 
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - ./Status/:/app:delegated
      - ./LocalStorage/:/root/local:delegated
```

Comment: Can you show how are you setting the path?

Comment: I'm reading it from a config.yml file

Comment: Sure, can I see how you set and read it?
Is it a spring-boot application or just plain spring?

Comment: I can't show you the full flow, cause it is multiple files, but here is how I read the resource path:   `XSSFWorkbook wb = getExcelWorkbook(getDataServiceConfig().getStatusesResource());`

Comment: it's just plain getter that response with a string

Comment: If you cannot show how you're setting this property and reading it, I can tell it will be slightly tricky to give you concrete advice on how to solve your problem.

Comment: Error occured inside of `if` or `else`?

Comment: I think that I can't do this because of docker

Comment: Are you trying to read a file that is on your local machine or is it in the docker instance?

Comment: on local machine

Comment: I should make a volume for 'files' folder, right?

Comment: The question is: Can the calling code access the local folder (which isn't clear by your examples). If the code is running in a docker instance that has no local folder `"Users\Karen"`, the error message will just be correct. If the code is on your local machine, the path must have flaws...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by adding an additional volume to `docker-compose` file:

```
services:

  rest-module:
    build:
      context: ./Status
    image: statusimage
    ports: 
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - ./Status/:/app:delegated
      - ./LocalStorage/:/root/local:delegated
      - /Users/karen/prog/files:/Users/karen/prog/files:delegated
```